# Fix the circular progress bar

Tags: android, android-studio, progress-bar, stopwatch

I am working on an Android app that is sort of like a stopwatch game. Anyway, As of right now the circular progress bar works correctly when started and stopped the first time but after that, the circular progress bar freaks out and I would like it to just keep going until the time runs out whether or not touch the stop button. Also, the reset button generates a huge random time if pressed while the timer is on. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is some code:

```
 /**
         * method to initialize the values for count down timer
         */


        /**
         * method to start count down timer
         */
        private void startCountDownTimer() {

            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeCountInMilliSeconds, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    timeUntilDone = (int)(millisUntilFinished/1000);
                    textViewTime.setText(hmsTimeFormatter(millisUntilFinished));

                    progressBarCircle.setProgress((int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000));

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                    textViewTime.setText(hmsTimeFormatter(timeCountInMilliSeconds));
                    // call to initialize the progress bar values
                    setProgressBarValues();
                    // hiding the reset icon
                    imageViewReset.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // changing stop icon to start icon
                    imageViewStartStop.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_start);
                    // making edit text editable
                    editTextMinute.setEnabled(true);
                    // changing the timer status to stopped
                    timerStatus = TimerStatus.STOPPED;
                    pauseClock();

                    stopWatch.setText("0:00:00");
                   // stopCountDownTimer();
                   // stopCountDownTimer();
                }

            }.start();
            if (timerStatus==TimerStatus.STOPPED) {
                countDownTimer.start();
            }
            else{
                startClock();
            }
        }

        /**
         * method to stop count down timer
         */
        private void stopCountDownTimer() {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }

        /**
         * method to set circular progress bar values
         */
        private void setProgressBarValues() {

            progressBarCircle.setMax((int) timeCountInMilliSeconds / 1000);
            progressBarCircle.setProgress((int) timeCountInMilliSeconds / 1000);
        }
```

/**

```
 * method to reset count down timer
     */
    private void reset() {
        startTime = 01; timeInMilliseconds =01; timeSwapBuff = 01; updateTime=01;
        stopWatch.setText("0:00:00");
        progressBarCircle.setProgress(timeUntilDone);
    }
```

Comment: Your issue is not understandable. Clarify and Share image also.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I think this is something that I just need to look how im calling my methods.

Comment: Are you mean to say you want to stop progress bar and start from previous stop ?

Comment: I would like the progress bar to act as a timer that is not associated with the timer in the middle, but i would like the start button to start both the timer and the progress bar but when i hit stop only the timer in the middle to stop and the progress bar will keep going until there the time is up.

Answer (score 0):

[working fine the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLxDN.pn)

[after pressing the start button again, it gives a random value and then the progress bar freaks out which you cant see because this is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVKUS.png)g